# is NSString value cannot be changed once it is provided a value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

Hi I got an information that NSString value is immutable and cannot be changed once it is provided a value.

But I have created and tested the following code:

```
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];    
NSLog(@"\n\nstr = %@",str);
str=@"asdasd";
NSLog(@"\n\n new str = %@",str);
```

and this gives "Hello" as first str value and "asdasd" as second str value. If it is so what is the relevance of calling NSString immutable?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

What you're doing on the third line is just creating a new string and pointing it with the str variable. You didn't change the original string, but rather made the variable point to a new one.

Comment: and potentially leaked the original string if you aren't using ARC.

Comment: @Juan: if it is possible to change the string value of str why NSString variable is called as immutable and what is the real difference between mutable string and immutable string?

Comment: @mttrb : I am using ARC and I dont understand what will happen to the original stringif I am not using ARC?

Comment: sorry I am new to Objective C

Comment: What is indeed immutable is the object that variable points to, you call it immutable because it does not have methods for changing its values, you just have methods for creating new strings out of the original one.

Comment: If you use arc, the compiler adds code to release your objects once they are not needed anymore, if you don't use arc, then you'd loose the reference of the original string and won't have the chance to release it anymore

Comment: No problem, that is kind of confusing subject :)

Comment: So in the above case, there are 2 objects and a variable pointing to the the 2 objects

Answer (score 5):

`NSString` is immutable. You cannot mutate it. Your confusion arises from the fact that your variable (pointer) is not `const`.

All you're doing is reassigning the pointer to a different immutable string.

If you were to attempt to append a string to either, then an error would ensue. This, specifically, is "…the relevance of calling NSString immutable". You should interpret this as the string instance may not be mutated, even though the variable you have declared may be assigned another NSString instance because it is not `const`.

You can make both the pointer const and the string immutable like so:

```
NSString * const aStr = @"aStr";
```

Comment: +1. Plus, in fact, in CoreFoudation a CFStringRef is declared as `struct __CFString *const`, and an NSMutableString is as `struct __CFString *`.

Comment: yup - this is how they achieved a typed, polymorphic declaration for the CFString type in C. (although the `const` is applied to the *type* in the case of `CFStringRef`, rather than the pointer -- `const struct __CFString *`)

Comment: Yeah... Seeing Apple's often illogical and overcomplicted source code makes me cry...

Comment: @H2CO3 actually, i agree with their approach on this one (in the context of a C interface). it's typesafe, and does not require redundant APIs for mutable/immutable variants. if it were not declared this way and typesafe, both CFStringGetLength and CFMutableStringGetLength would be required. if it were not typesafe, it would fill the clients' code with nasty casts. it may appear convoluted, but it serves a good purpose. of course, many people can just use objc interfaces instead.

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing an immutable object and a constant pointer (plus you're leaking memory). Here you don't really change the NSString *instance* (that is, the object itself), but just a pointer to it. The point is that you can assign different instances of an NSString to the same variable, it won't change the internal contents of the object, nor would it make it respond to NSMutableString's mutation messages such as `appendString` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use this will sol your problem...

```
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello"];    
NSLog(@"\n\nstr = %@",str);
str = nil;
str=@"asdasd";
NSLog(@"\n\n new str = %@",str);
```

This some basic that you should know..

```
NSString *s1 = @"string1";
NSString *s2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"string2"];
NSString *s3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"string3"];
```

s1 in this case is a pointer to a constant string. s2 and s3 both point to new strings that you've created, but s2 has been retained for you, and s3 has been autoreleased. If you just need a temporary object, the autoreleased object s3 or the constant object s1 are good choices. If you need to keep the string around, you should use s2 (actually now that I think about it s1 will work in this case too - it's not really idiomatic, though).

You can make s1 or s3 equivalent to s2 by sending them a retain message. You could also turn s2 into an equivalent object by sending it an autorelease message.